# what does $X_{s-}$ mean in the integration by parts formula for the Ito integral?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

[The integration by parts formula for the Itō integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C5%8D_calculus#Integration_by_parts) is

> If $X$ and $Y$ are semimartingales then
>   $$
>     X_tY_t = X_0Y_0+\int_0^t X_{s-}\,dY_s + \int_0^t Y_{s-}\,dX_s + [X,Y]_t
> $$
>   where $[X, Y]$ is the quadratic covariation process.

I was wondering what $X_{s-}$ means? Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's defined pointwise by
$$
X_{s-}=\lim_{t\to s,t<s} X_t
$$